# rpm mock - complex rpm building

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec, mock

Lets say I want to make an RPM which delivers an Apache Webserver with its own OpenSSL:

```
/mydir/apache_postfix1
/mydir/openssl_postfix1
```

Since Apache mod_ssl requires a real OpenSSL installation I have to `configure --prefix=/mydir/openssl`, `make`, `make install` OpenSSL to `/mydir/openssl` so Apache with `mod_ssl` can actually compile with `configure --with-ssl=/mydir/openssl`.

Unthinkable on a build server (Jenkins) with no permissions on anything outside its jobs directory. But I need to build Apache with OpenSSL and package it into an RPM (to deliver postfixed multiple Apaches each with their own OpenSSL).

So I thought that `mock` is the solution (which is more likely to be installed on the build server than we get any user/install permissions).

But I haven't found a full documentation on how I can use mock to use rpmbuilds full capabilities.

I tried `mock -r epel-7-x68_64 example.src.rpm` but it is looking for `/builddir/build/SPECS/example.spec` and so failing ... why? from where did it got this file?

This was just an example, the real problem consists of 7 independent software packages which should get configured/compiled against each other so they act as a single service ... and packaged into a single RPM for Red Hat Satellite to be delivered onto >200 servers ... without actually installing them on the build server ...

Any help or a link to usable documentation/examples are highly appreciable!

Answer (score 1):

The best sources of documentation would be the [mock source code](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock/wiki), the [official rpm documentation](http://rpm.org/documentation), the [rpm packaging guide](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io), and any further documentation any of those recommend.  As for your posted example, it appears your `example.src.rpm` package does not have a proper spec file in the correct place for mock to work with.

mock will take an input of a src.rpm file to rebuild, or you can use a spec file and sources directory to build a source rpm (SRPM).  With some extra config, you can even use mock directly with source code checkouts.  Once you have mock installed and a user configured to use it (mock will complain if you attempt to use as root, an unprivileged user needs to be in the mock group), it is fairly simple to use:

```
yumdownloader --source openssl
mkdir rpm-results
mock -r epel-7-x68_64 --resultdir=rpm-results openssl-*.src.rpm
```

That will rebuild the distribution provided OpenSSL and place the resulting packages in the rpm-results dir.  To make changes to the distribution provided package, you would want to install the src.rpm, make your changes, then build the resulting rpm files:

```
yumdownloader --source openssl
rpm -ivh openssl-*.src.rpm
# usually this installs to ~/rpmbuild
# make your changes to ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/* and ~/rpmbuild/SPEC/openssl.spec as necesary
mkdir rpm-results
mock -r epel-7-x68_64 --resultdir=rpm-results --buildsrpm ~/rpmbuild/SPEC/openssl.spec
mock -r epel-7-x68_64 --resultdir=rpm-results rpm-results/openssl-*.src.rpm
```

I am not sure if newer versions do not require the two step build (SRPM => RPM), but this is how we have been using mock at my shop.  You would likely want/need to do that for each package you are attempting to rebuild.  I would not advise packaging everything into a single package like you ask, but nothing technically stops you from doing that.  You would just need to make you own spec file that combines everything together or use a different tool such as [FPM](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki).

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. I got mock running and rebuilding my SRPM but I have the same problem as without mock: within mock's chroot I can't make install any of the packages because the SRPM rebuild is run as non-root so it can't "install" anything during the build (and installing them into BUILDROOT does not work because other packages need them bo be installed into their true path to compile ...). Is there any way the SRPM rebuild process can be run as root within mock's chroot? again this all should work on a build server with a non-root user!

Comment: Not sure if your issue is caused by incorrectly using mock or if you are incorrectly building packages.  The mock user has full access to the mock chroot, when I enter the chroot I am the root user.  You install a package into the mock chroot with `mock --install somepackage.rpm`.  Packages are installed into the mock chroot in the exact place the RPM tells them to install it.  You do not mention how you are attempting to build packages, maybe a spec file you are trying or some specific errors you are seeing so others can know what you need help with.

Comment: appearently the srpm rebuild is run as user 'mockbuild' (aka. the user running 'mock') while mock's chroot is populated as root and so the srpm rebuild process can't create directories at top level of mock's chroot because it's owned by root:root ...

Comment: The files should belong to the mock group so users in the mock group have access to them.  You should never have to interact directly with the chroot anyway, just use the tools mock provides to manage everything.  I guess I still do not follow what your problem is, why is the ownership of the files causing an issue for you?

Comment: yes I know that they "should" belong to the mock group but every directory in the chroot belongs to root:root except the '/builddir' directory obviously ... its a fresh mock installation and I also deletet mock's chroot directory (the one with the root and result directories) and populated it multiple times but as I know the chroot is populated as root user ... trying it out is more reliable than any docs ...

Comment: Okay, so what is your issue that is manifested by the permissions being root?  Can the user in the mock group use the mock tools?  You should not be interacting with the chroot, but instead use the tools mock provides.  If the mock tools are not working for the mock user, then something would not be working correctly and need additional troubleshooting.  Why don't you show what you are trying out and is not working, because otherwise I seem to not be able to determine what your issue/question is.

Comment: given an SRPM with a SPEC File with:

'%build
mkdir -p /app/openssl_ssp'

results in: 'mkdir /app/openssl_ssp: Permissions denied' if run with 'mock -r epel-7-x86_64 --rebuild ssp-0.0.1.src.rpm' ... because mock's chroot is populated as root and so all directories except /builddir belong to root:root, my current workaround is to 'mock --shell "mkdir /app && chmod 777 /app"' so the SRPM rebuild process can write to /app ...

Comment: You are building your packages incorrectly, you are not supposed to make any directories in /.  You should be making the spec file to handle everything within /buildroot (better practice would be to learn the RPM macros) and then at the end tell RPM to install everything into the location(s) you want to use.  If you look at how a an existing spec file installs files, you should notice it is always against %{buildroot} which is the rpm macro for where everything should happen.  The %install and %files steps determine where files in your package will be installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75549/discussion-between-pali-and-gracefulrestart).

Answer (score 1):

I am a maintainer of Mock, so I should provide you an answer. But I really cannot, because you did not specify what is actually a problem.

I can only elaborate on how Mock works and resolve some of your confusions.

When you call `mock -r fedora-27-x86_64`, then Mock will do (skipping some boring details):

1. `dnf install --installroot /var/lib/mock/fedora-27-x86_64/root @buildsys-build` This will install minimal system in separate directory. Further in this answer I will refer to `/var/lib/mock/fedora-27-x86_64/root` as $CHROOT.
2. Mock will extract your `example.src.rpm`. Especially it will put spec file into `$CHROOT/builddir/build/SPECS` and tar ball into `$CHROOT/builddir/build/SOURCES`.
3. Mock will parse your spec file and install all packages listed in BuildRequires into $CHROOT. (This is done as root).
4. Mock will then chroot() into $CHROOT and run there `rpmbuild -ba /builddir/build/SPECS/example.spec`. This is done as unprivileged user (with the UID equal to your UID). This is done because running rpmbuild have always been discouraged and can lead to serious problems.

So if you want to install some additional packages in chroot., you should not do that from within spec file by calling yum/dnf install (especially because rpm is not reentrant). But you should specify those packages in BuildRequires and provide a repository with those packages.

You can provide a repository either using `mockchain -a REPOS` (mockchain is a thin layer on top of mock) or by:

```
cp /etc/mock/fedora-27-x86_64.cfg ~/my-custom-fedora-27-x86_64.cfg
#add your repository to ~/my-custom-fedora-27-x86_64.cfg
mock -r ~/my-custom-fedora-27-x86_64.cfg example.src.rpm
```

If you have 7 src.rpm packages depended on each other, then probably the best way is to call `mockchain 1.src.rpm 2.src.rpm .... 7.src.rpm` and mockchain will create a temporary repository for results and try to build those packages in a naive way in `while at-least-one-package-build do another loop`.

If you specify what is actually your problem, then I can provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Many thanks for explaining what Mock is actually doing! Thing is I have to build 7 software packages from source because most of them are configured (./configure --with-openssl=/bla etc.) to use some other of those software packages (header files, installation directory, etc.). So I wanted to use Mock so I can install them all in their real paths (buildroot is not working because after packaging them into the RPM and installing them most things are broken since they have hardcoded paths in their binaries). But mock's rebuild is run as mockbuild user and has no permissions to mkdir /bla ...

Comment: ??? When you build your custom openssl, and then put is as BuildRequires, then it is put into $CHROOT, which *is* a root during buildtime.  Note that buildroot is (from host perspective) $CHROOT/%{buildroot}/ and it is used for creating layout which will go into %files. Not for installing dependencies.